# How much did Gold’s gym in Venice Beach cost to belong to or train at in its golden age?

Tags: bodybuilding, gym

And why did all of the greatest body builders apparently train there?

If this is better suited to history, then please feel free to migrate it.

Comment: The Arnold Schwarzenegger documentary on Netflix actually answers the second question.  It's mostly because Joe Gold and Arnold brought so many other bodybuilders to the gym. They took photos and published magazines advertising how awesome being a bodybuilder in Venice Beach was which brought more people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](https://insidebodybuilding.com/the-history-of-golds-gym/), the initial dues were $60, and increased to $200  in the 1980s.

> In 1977 Pumping Iron finally hit US scenes and although fewer than one million Americans ended up seeing it that year, a buzz had been created. Soon after the movie’s release we saw stars such as Clint Eastwood and Muhammad Ali begin to show up at Golds looking to train at the Mecca of bodybuilding. Hollywood and popular culture became hooked on muscle.
>
> The following years saw Arnold become a movie star with flicks such as Conan, Ferrigno become the Hulk and mainstream actors like Stallone, Weathers and Eastwood display chiseled physiques in their movies. Sprague’s Golds suddenly began to feature in fashion magazines and even a piece on 60 minutes. During this time, dues at Golds reached $200, a far cry from the $60 Joe Gold had charged in the beginning.

As for the popularity, the same article quotes Al Antuck in *Ironman* as saying

> Gold’s is a bodybuilders’ gym. Here you won’t find business men types who work out just to stay in shape. Most members are bodybuilders who work hard to gain bulk, density and symmetry, and they work hard with minimum time for kibitzing or goofing-off.

Comment: Was that $60/ month, or annua?

Comment: That's actually a good question. I'm not certain, although the fact that current premium dues are in the range of$30-40 plus a $50 annual fee, I'd be inclined to say annual.